# Database in SQL server stack in recovery mode

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I was restoring my database, but it never finished restoring. I am certain I used the `RECOVERY` option and *not* `NORECOVERY`. I also tried as if it was a new data base, but it still hangs and never completes when recovering the database.

Some data could be important:

size of me file .bak 2GB
SQL Server 2012 (Management Studio)
SO Windows Server 2012 R2
[image: here is the 'issue' it appears to be on a loop]

Any help getting this database to finish restoring is appreciated.

Comment: That last backup taken was two weeks ago!? That's not cool.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of the larger log file restoring slowly. Please try the following:

```
RESTORE DATABASE DBName WITH RECOVERY
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check that there's no IO-intensive processes running other than SQL. If the disks are slow, recovery will take longer than expected. For more information see [Why SQL Server Database Is In Recovery Mode](http://mssqllover.blogspot.com/2016/08/database-stuck-in-recovery-mode.html)